# python + pymongo: how to insert a new field on an existing document in mongo from a for loop

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I'm using a for loop in python to loop over the result of a query with pymongo. Here is the code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()
db = connection.Test

myDocs = db.Docs.find( { "geolocCountry" : { "$exists" : False } } )

for b in myDrives:
    my_lat = b['TheGpsLog'][0]['latitude']
    my_long = b['TheGpsLog'][0]['longitude']

    myGeolocCountry = DoReverseGeocode(lat_start,long_start) 
    #    Here I perform a reverse geocoding, it does not matter for this example. 
    #    The important thing is: it returns a string, like 'US', 'UK', etc...
```

The question I have is, how can I insert the variable `myGeolocCountry` into the non existing field `geolocCountry` on the existing document (`b`)?

I tried with

```
b['geolocCountry'] = myGeolocCountry
```

but it didn't work at all, it does not even produce an error.

Thanks

Comment: where do you get myDrives from?

Comment: You say db.Docs but Docs is actually a collection.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should execute an update query like this:

```
db.Doc.update({"_id": b["_id"]}, {"$set": {"geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry}})
```

Comment: It worked, your solution has a small mistake, tho. `"myGeolocCountry"` don't need `"` because it's a variable :-)     Thanks

Answer (score 15):

For **pymongo > 3**

```
db.Doc.update_one({"_id": b["_id"]}, {"$set": {"geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry}})
```

In case of multiple updates:

```
db.Doc.update_many({"geolocCountry": {"$exists": False}}, {"$set": {"geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry}})
```

For **pymongo < 3**

above/previous answers are correct

```
db.Doc.update({"_id": b["_id"]}, {"$set": {"geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry}})
```

In case of multiple updates:

```
db.Doc.update({"geolocCountry": {"$exists": False}}, {"$set": {"geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry}})
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the function [`update()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) in order to update records in your collection.

With update you can specify a query (just like you have above with `collection.find()` but also provide a second dict that defines how you want to update the documents found in the query.
something like:

```
db.Docs.update({"geolocCountry":{"$exists":False}}, {"$set": "geolocCountry": myGeolocCountry})
```

Check out the API for the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

you need to save the collection after update.

```
for b in myDrives:
    my_lat = b['TheGpsLog'][0]['latitude']
    my_long = b['TheGpsLog'][0]['longitude']

    myGeolocCountry = DoReverseGeocode(lat_start,long_start)

    b['geolocCountry'] = myGeolocCountry
    **db.Docs.save(b)**
```